# Excel Trust Center Breaking Documents

Tags: vba, excel

We have staff that use a from created by a state government office. It is full of VBA code, smaller macros, and active x controls. This document changes often and does not have a publisher certificate. When a user opens the document and allows the code to run it bugs out. (formatting is wrong on newly created sheets etc). I have contacted the document creators and they claim it's "system corruption" but I doubt this to be the case since this occurs on every single copy of excel 2010 we have. My fix has be to disable the trust center almost entirely. This is really not acceptance and what I would like to ask is there any way to set excel to both trust and enable documents from either a certain site or with a name containing an phrase or a name?

Comment: Please read> [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: @DavidG. Unless the question was edited between when we both read it, I have to disagree. This is a perfectly acceptable question regarding Excel (though it may be easily solved with a Google search).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can in `Trust Center Settings` under the `Trusted Locations` tab you can trust a location, or a single file by hitting the `Add new location...` button and adding the location to the folder or files you want to trust.

Comment: I've tried that as a shim, it still breaks active x controls